# Keydown producing unexpected result. HTML5 Game

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, keydown

So I am at the very beginning stages of creating my first platform style game in html5.So far I have only implemented left and right movement and no 'gravity' or collision detection is at play.

However, I've already hit an issue.

If you go left or right for a short period of time the 'character' acts as intended (I use character loosely as it's the map that is actually moving). If, however, you hold the key down the map moves too fast.

I figure the issue is that the keydown event listener is listening all of the time, there for moving the map is moving before each tick or frame of the game.

So my question is how can I make the keydown increase the map offset only on every tick of the game (20 milliseconds).

Here is my JSFiddle: [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dYC2D/)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
    var dir = event.which;

    if(dir == directions.LEFT){
        mapOffsetX += mapOffsetDistanceX;
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    if(dir == directions.RIGHT){
        mapOffsetX -= mapOffsetDistanceX;
        event.preventDefault();
    };
});

document.addEventListener('keyup',function(event){
    var dir = event.which;

    if(dir == directions.LEFT){
        mapOffsetX -= mapOffsetDistanceX;
    };

    if(dir == directions.RIGHT){
        mapOffsetX += mapOffsetDistanceX;
    };
});

initFloorObject(100,c.height/2,300,20,0,0,0,1);

var myInt = setInterval(function(){

clearScreen();

for(var i=0;i<floorObject.length;i++){
    floorObject[i][0] = parseInt(floorObject[i][0])+mapOffsetX;
};

drawChar();
drawFloorObjects();

},20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set variable to `false` every time you `keydown` and set it back to `true` every 20 milliseconds.

```
var isKeydownAvailable = true;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    var dir = event.which;
    if(isKeydownAvailable){
        if (dir == directions.LEFT) {
            mapOffsetX += mapOffsetDistanceX;
            event.preventDefault();
        };

        if (dir == directions.RIGHT) {
            mapOffsetX -= mapOffsetDistanceX;
            event.preventDefault();
        };
        isKeydownAvailable = false;
    };
});
```

In the interval, reset the `isKeydownAvailable` to `true`.

```
var myInt = setInterval(function () {

    clearScreen();

    for (var i = 0; i < floorObject.length; i++) {
        floorObject[i][0] = parseInt(floorObject[i][0]) + mapOffsetX;
    };

    drawChar();
    drawFloorObjects();
    isKeydownAvailable = true;

}, 20);
```

Comment: Would I not use intervalTime as the second argument when setting myInt in the event listener?

Comment: Aah yes you would. I believe I read the question wrong. By "how can I make the keydown increase the map offset only on every tick of the game (20 milliseconds)", do you mean to call event listener every 20 milliseconds when player is holding the key down?

Comment: Yeah, just what I mean. Would your solution be applicable?

Comment: I have edited the answer. It should be applicable. Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aU7ta/5/. I have changed the interval to 1 second so it is more clear to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use booleans for actions and check for them inside your interval.
On keydown you set the boolean `isMovingLeft` to true, then you add the offset in your interval function only `if(isMovingLeft)`.
Do that for the other actions and you are good to go.